# iOS Synchrounous calling asynchronous methods

Tags: ios, asynchronous, delegates, synchronous, countdowntimer

I am calling checkWeathermethod then I will store into the database by calling storeWeatherIntoDB. After storeWeatherIntoDB completed, it will call the sendWeatherToServer via SQLdelegate. After sendWeatherToServer completed, I will a variable to notify checkWeathermethod.

Question: How checkWeathermethod wait all these process to complete so that it can return the variable?

1. (int)checkWeathermethod  --call--> storeWeatherIntoDB
2. storeWeatherIntoDB carry out process
3. storeWeatherIntoDB delegate return  --call--> sendWeatherToServer
4. sendWeatherToServer carry out process
5. sendWeatherToServer delegate return --notify--> checkWeathermethod to return int

I am thinking of using Notification center to notify checkWeathermethod but I don't know how to make it wait for the processes.

If not I wish to have a timer with 10 sec timeout if nothing return 
If result return within 10 sec, checkWeathermethod will return the int.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html). For instance, if you want to execute code after `storeWeatherIntoDB` has finished, you can do it this way:

```
- (void)checkWeathermethod {
    [self storeWeatherIntoDB:^(int returnCode) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // When you get here, the weather has been stored on the server.
            // E.g. you can now show success or failure here
            if (returnCode == 0) {
                // OK
            }
            else {
                // Error
            }
        });
    }];
}

- (void)storeWeatherIntoDB:(void(^)(int returnCode))completionBlock {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        // Store weather into db here.
        // You can do this even synchronously.
        int returnCode = [self storeWeather];

        // Call callback
        if (completionBlock) {
            completionBlock(returnCode);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I need sendWeatherToServer return value to checkWeathermethod. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes of course. Simply store the return value (e.g. `int`) in a variable and pass it back to the method. I will edit the answer to show how this is done.

Comment: thanks. I will look at the block. So it is not possible for (int)checkWeathermethod be the one which return the int? I have to use a new variable for it?

Comment: As the method is asynchronous, you will only know the return code once `storeWeatherIntoDB` is completed. Then you can store the return code in a variable for instance. But if you need to have it elsewhere once the code has run, simply add a completion block to `checkWeathermethod` as well. This will allow you to pass the return code.